# Python-3 JSON call generates error from internal modules only on some systems

Tags: json, python-3.x

Sorry if this is a bit vague. I'll try to clarify as much as I can, but I have no idea how to troubleshoot this...

I have a Python script that makes an API call to return a float value.

It works as expected on two of my systems. here's the code snippet:

```
#Make API request
api_response = requests.request("POST", source_server + query_endpoint, headers=query_headers, data=query_payload)

myfilter = json.loads(api_response.content)
netstate = (myfilter['networkQuality'])
netstate = float(netstate)

print(netstate)
```

I've shared the script with a colleague, who assures me he's running the same version of Python (3.9.0) and has the prerequisite libraries installed (requests, JSON and HTTP.cookiejar), but when he runs the scripts he gets the following error (sorry for the screenshot, but I don't have access to his system):

[image]

I have absolutely no idea what this error is telling me, nor how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Using `api_response.text` is probably better anyway. Also, you should always chech that the request was succesfull (e.g. `api_response.status_code` or `api_response.raise_for_status()`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the script is working OK on three systems (I tried another one, just to verify). Its that error message I need to understand and correct.

Comment: The error message says that the json is invalid. Did you take a look at that what you are passing in?